# Efficient way of putting word lengths from text file into array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I read a text file using scanner, removed punctuation from each line, and stored all the words in a single string array.

I'm trying to put the frequency of word lengths in an array, for example, strings with length 1 will go into another array with index 1, strings with length 2 will go into the array with index 2, to length 15 or greater, ultimately until I have all of the lengths of the word counted and put into my new array.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this instead of iterating through the array of words, and making 15 else-if statements for each word length?

Clarification: Is there any way to do this without importing any packages? It seems like the only way to do this is by iterating through it by the word length frequency array, e.g. 15 times using a double for loop or by running it through a 15 else-if statement block.

Comment: does the length of the longest word is known?

Comment: You may want to use `HashMap` and `ArrayList` and `BufferedReader`.

Comment: @amirag I stopped my array at 15 words or greater.

Comment: ok, thanks. i'll write the algoritm

Comment: Can't really see how this question is the same as the above. both about different things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `String`'s length as the index.

```
int[16] leng = {0}; // put 0 in all of the cells
String all, word;
.
.
.
leng[word.length()-1]++;
```

Every time you have a word with length of `i` it will add 1 to the location `i-1` (i > 0). 
The first cell (leng[0]) will contain how many words with length of 1 was. 
The second cell (leng[1]) will contain how many words with length of 2 was. 
.
.
.
The `n` cell (leng[n-1]) will contain how many words with the length of n was.

You have 16 cells (0-14 and 15+) so you can do the following: 
You can do it with one condition:

```
if(word.length() < 15)
{
    leng[word.length()-1]++;
}
else
{
    leng[15]++;
}
```

Another way (the same but with one line):

```
length[(word.length()<15)(word.length()):(15)]++;
```

Good luck :)

Comment: forgot to explain: `all` = the full `String`, all of the words. `word` = the word you are now checking.

Answer (score 0):

Create array of lists and use string's length as index in the array. Something like that:

```
List<String>[] lists = new ArrayList[16];
...
lists[str.length].add(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is using a HashMap like  in your case `HashMap<K,V> list` like this example

```
HashMap<Integer,ArrayList> list = new HashMap<>();
list.put(lenght,new ArrayList <String>());
list.get(lenght);
```

More info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).